# Does JTA support Clustering of application servers?

Tags: transactions, jta, spring-transactions, transactional, distributed-transactions

I have successfully implemented JTA over multiple databases at different location;commit and rollback.
All i need to know is if i could work with different application servers?
Will clustering of different application server will be supported by JPA?
also if there are any databases where it cannot be implemented(other then RDBMS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i searched and came with following conclusion :

JTA doesn't support clustering of various application server.([reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/JTA_Clustering_Limitations1.html))

JTA supports all RDBMS as they support atomicity and few NOSQL db such as [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/).

I will edit if i came across other conclusion. :)